# R: Purpose of specifying column classes when reading data table

Tags: class, dataframe

I am taking an intro to R Programming course on Coursera and I'm wondering what the purpose is of specifying the column classes when reading a large table using read.table() in the following situation:

```
initial <- read.table("datatable.txt", nrows=100)  
classes <- sapply(initial, class)
tabAll <- read.table("datatable.txt", colClasses=classes)
```

The code is from a short video on reading large data tables. For context, I've attached a picture of the relevant slide from the video. The instructor says that doing the above will make read.table() run "MUCH" faster--but I don't understand why. I can see the point if we already know the column classes, but in the above code we're just reading the table twice. Why would this be faster?

Thanks.[image]